# Why does my Python app keeps expiring in Azure?

Tags: flask, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, workflow, azure-webapps

I have a Python web app built with Flask hosted with an Azure for Students account that is deployed by a workflow in GitHub. From time to time when people try to use the app, it just won't open. And every time it happens, I check it in GitHub actions, under the last run of the workflow, and it says that my Python app has expired. So I manually run the workflow, the app is deployed again and then it's back online - which solves the problem but this isn't supposed to be happening. I would like to know why the app keeps expiring and if there is a way of preventing it from happening.

I've already looked to see if it has something to do with the fact that I use a student's account, but I've found nothing related between this and the app's expiration. I've also thought it could have something to do with GitHub's workflow expiring, but also couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Azure for Students docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/students/) you get:

- 10 web, mobile, or API apps with 1 GB storage 1 hour per day